# How to change a datetime format in python?

Tags: python, datetime

How can one make `2020/09/06 15:59:04`  out of  `06-09-202015u59m04s`.

This is my code:

```
my_time = '06-09-202014u59m04s'
date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_time, '%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%S')
print(date_object)
```

This is the error I receive:

```
ValueError: time data '06-09-202014u59m04s' does not match format '%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%S'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> my_time = '06-09-202014u59m04s'
>>> dt_obj = datetime.strptime(my_time,'%d-%m-%Y%Hu%Mm%Ss')
```

Now you need to do some format changes to get the answer as the datetime object always prints itself with `:` so you can do any one of the following:

Either get a new format using `strftime`:

```py
>>> dt_obj.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
'2020/09/06 14:59:04'
```

Or you can simply use `.replace()` by converting datetime object to `str`:

```py
>>> str(dt_obj).replace('-','/')
'2020/09/06 14:59:04'
```

Answer (score 2):

As your error says what you give does not match format - `%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%S` - means you are expecting after year: letter T `hour`:`minutes`:`seconds` when in example show it is `hour`u`minutes`m`seconds`s without T, so you should do:

```
import datetime
my_time = '06-09-202014u59m04s'
date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_time, '%d-%m-%Y%Hu%Mm%Ss')
print(date_object)
```

Output:

```
2020-09-06 14:59:04
```

Comment: I think your quiet close. But as you can see I need it with `/` between year, month and day.

Answer (score 1):

You need to always make sure that your desired date format should match up with your required format.

```
from datetime import datetime

date_object = datetime.strptime("06-09-202015u59m04s", '%d-%m-%Y%Hu%Mm%Ss')
print(date_object.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Output

```
2020/09/06 15:59:04
```

Comment: The similar answer is posted above, consider posting answers if you have different solution than ones already posted.

Comment: I need the `/` between the year, month and date as you can see in my desired output.

Comment: @JenilDave my bad I did not see that answer